# Magento2: position in category in product's list.phtml

Tags: magento2, product-list, position

Magento can sort products by a manually set position in a category. When I echo the select of a collection (`echo $productCollection->getSelect()`) it shows as `` cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position `` in the query.

But the products in the resulting list do not contain this position. How could I get it into the product list?

Thank you

Comment: Try echoing $productCollection->addFieldToSelect('position')->getSelect() and check the result.

Comment: I was getting the same issue, Please share here if you find a solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

The position was there all along. There is no need to alter the collection. The field's name is `cat_index_position`.